# Can base classes see the protected fields of derived classes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, scope

I don't know if this has to do with how FindControl works or how scope works.  But my base class is having a hard time seeing the fields of child classes.  Currently I'm planning have the derived class set a property in the base class, but there are a lot of derived classes, so that isn't a very attractive solution.

```
public class BasePage:Page
{
    public void DoSomethingWithDerivedPageControl()
    {
        //foo is always null.
        Control foo = FindControl("Foo");
    }
}

public class DerivedPage : BasePage
{
    //In real life, this is the code generated .aspx.designer.cs file.
    protected Label Foo;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FindControl` doesn't use fields - it uses the controls which have been added to the page, and checks their ids.

Presumably your control hasn't been added to the page at the time when `DoSomethingWithDerivedPageControl` is called.

It would be helpful if you could tell us what you're really trying to achieve... if all your derived types should have a control called `Foo`, why not just put it in the base class to start with?

Comment: Ah! You set me on the right track.  It was in the control collection of of a Table control.  I had to do a recursive search to find it.  Couldn't move it to base class because it was a label embedded in a slightly different table on each page.

Answer (score 2):

```
public abstract class BasePage:Page 
{ 
    abstract protected Label Foo {get;}
    public void DoSomethingWithDerivedPageControl() 
    { 
        Control foo = this.Foo;
    } 
} 

public class DerivedPage : BasePage 
{ 
    override protected Label Foo { get; set;} 
}
```

Now, I suspect that's not wholy fulfilling your need.  But, a base class doesn't/cant' know about it's children.  Your only option to find a random field in a child class, is to just ignore the fact that they are base/derived, and just use reflection of it, as if it were an unrelated class.

Comment: @Miochael Meadows:  Ya'know... as I was writing the abstract property, I said to myself, "I gotta remember to make the class abstract..."

Comment: Elegant solution, too bad I don't have enough control over how visual studio code generates the .aspx.designer.cs files-- I wouldn't have a way to add the override to the declaration. (Or is there?)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your title question, inheritance runs from base class to derived class, not the other way.  A member is either defined in a base class, and inherited by the derived class, or defined in the derived class and unknown to the base.

It stands to reason that a base class referring to a child member couldn't compile, since the base class definition has no knowledge of that member.

Answer (score 0):

Whoa, this is scary that your even trying to do this.  The base class shouldn't know anything about the derived class.